# jquery - Hide checkbox for table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

Hello, how do I hide the checkbox for the table row that always contains the word "Fixed" as a link? Please see screenshot. The ID and names are dynamic and always change. I tried this but had no luck:

```
$( "tr:contains('Fixed')" ).find( ":checkbox" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Comment: Inspections are hardly readable. But did you try `.css( {"display": "none" })`

Comment: Would not it be better to put the disabled attribute on the checkbox?

Comment: Posting a zoomed-out partial screenshot of a section of your code in the inspector is not a useful way to show us the code you're working with. You need to post the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$('a').filter( function() {
    return ~$(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('fixed');
} ).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').hide();
```

The `.toLowerCase()` makes it case-insensitive, and the `~` is there because if `indexOf()` doesn't match the string, it returns -1 (0 means "at position 0"), so the bitwise NOT converts -1 into the falsey value of 0, and everything else into truthy values.

You can improve this by adding a selector to the front so it doesn't crawl every single `<a>` tag - something like `$('table').find('a')` or better yet the ID, or something more identifiable.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but what does the `:checkbox` CSS selector look for? A `type`? I tried googling it for for selecting types I only found `element[type=...]` like examples.

Comment: @AlejandroIván it's a jQuery selector, not a CSS one - [see the docs](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

`$( "tr a:contains('Fixed')" ).find( ":checkbox" ).css( "display", "none" );`